# Did this story from S09E02 reference any old episode?

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

In this weekend's episode,

> Missy tells a story of how The Doctor escaped from "50 android assassins" (she may have rounded up), by using the energy from their weapons to charge his teleporter wristband, and then afterwards fell into a nest of "vampire monkeys". The actual sequence was shot with Capaldi, with the justification that Missy doesn't differentiate between what face he's wearing so "let's give it to the eyebrows", but the clear implication is that it may well have been a different incarnation of the Doctor.

Does this correlate to any episode of the original show?

Comment: There were brief shots of what looked like Tom Baker and William Hartnell (maybe CGI versions) in there as well.

Comment: I haven't seen *every* old episode but I don't remember anything like invisible android assassins.

Comment: Didn't she say it was before the Doctor stole the TARDIS?

Comment: @tilley31 She said he didn't have the TARDIS. He's been separated from the TARDIS on various occasions.

Comment: I thought the brief shot was supposed to be Pertwee, not Hartnell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No.

Vampire monkeys don't feature in any previous episode of *Doctor Who*, and the story about the android assassins doesn't seem to have appeared before either. Although the basic idea has, e.g. in *Flatline* (series 8) Clara says:

> Rule number one of being the Doctor. Use your enemy's power against them.

This also makes sense given that they filmed the scene with Capaldi. They weren't afraid of using clips of older Doctors in the previous episode; if this story *had* been based on an old episode, they could have used footage from that episode instead. (Unless it was one of the 100-odd 'missing episodes', of course...)

Comment: Actually vampire monkeys were a thing in a comic: http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Vampire_monkey - Yeah, I have no idea why they exist either.